# Foreign key referring to primary keys across multiple tables?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have to two tables namely employees_ce and employees_sn under the database employees.

They both have their respective unique primary key columns.

I have another table called deductions, whose foreign key column I want to reference to primary keys of employees_ce as well as employees_sn. Is this possible?

for example

```
employees_ce
--------------
empid   name
khce1   prince

employees_sn
----------------
empid   name
khsn1   princess
```

so is this possible?

```
deductions
--------------
id      name
khce1   gold
khsn1   silver
```

Answer (score 114):

Assuming that I have understood your scenario correctly, this is what I would call the *right* way to do this:

Start from a higher-level description of your database! You have employees, and employees can be "ce" employees and "sn" employees (whatever those are). In object-oriented terms, there is a class "employee", with two sub-classes called "ce employee" and "sn employee".

Then you translate this higher-level description to three tables: `employees`, `employees_ce` and `employees_sn`:

- `employees(id, name)`
- `employees_ce(id, ce-specific stuff)`
- `employees_sn(id, sn-specific stuff)`

Since all employees are employees (duh!), every employee will have a row in the `employees` table. "ce" employees also have a row in the `employees_ce` table, and "sn" employees also have a row in the `employees_sn` table. `employees_ce.id` is a foreign key to `employees.id`, just as `employees_sn.id` is.

To refer to an employee of any kind (ce or sn), refer to the `employees` table. That is, the foreign key you had trouble with should refer to that table!

Comment: How do you make ce and sn mutually exclusive? Since an employee cannot be at the same time ce and sn, it would be good practice to reflect that in the database. I'm having this problem right now.

Comment: I think multiple column keys could help with the problem in my previous comment... looking up that right now.

Comment: You can force the employee to be in only one the table (and the correct one) by storing a type in the base table as well as the derived tables. Make the primary key id, a unique key on (id,type), the child tables' foreign key be on (id, type), and put a CHECK constraint on each child table to only have the correct type. Or, if you database does global check constraints (and without huge speed penalty), you can of course just do a NOT EXISTS check.

Comment: Check **[this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59232905/484814)** for full explanation and implementation details.

Comment: how to know an employee with a specific  id is 'se' or 'sn' ?

Answer (score 26):

You can probably add two foreign key constraints (honestly: I've never tried it), but it'd then insist the parent row exist in both tables.

Instead you probably want to create a supertype for your two employee subtypes, and then point the foreign key there instead. (Assuming you have a good reason to split the two types of employees, of course).

```
                 employee       
employees_ce     ————————       employees_sn
————————————     type           ————————————
empid —————————> empid <——————— empid
name               /|\          name
                    |  
                    |  
      deductions    |  
      ——————————    |  
      empid ————————+  
      name
```

`type` in the employee table would be `ce` or `sn`.

Comment: I tried adding multiple foreign keys, they worked but, while adding a record, java derby tells me both foreign key constraints have been violated!

Comment: I just tried it on PostgreSQL, and it works there. Did you have the parent record in both tables?

Comment: parent record you mean to say, the empid?

Comment: Surely the problem has been shifted from the "deductions" table to the "employee" table. How would you reference potentially different Entities based on a type?

Comment: @gawpertron: Well, the empid is unique across all types. You can use the 'type' field to see which sub-table you need to reference. Or just `LEFT JOIN` all of them, if there are few enough. When not using the 'employee' base table, the primary key could not be declared (because it's be referencing tableA or tableB or…); now it can be. The wisdom of splitting `employees_ce` and `employees_sn` was assumed, and that assumption is noted.

Answer (score 21):

Actually I do this myself. I have a table called 'Comments' which contains comments for records in 3 other tables. Neither solution actually handles everything you probably want it to. In your case, you would do this:

**Solution 1:**

1. Add a tinyint field to employees_ce and employees_sn that has a default value which is different in each table (This field represents a 'table identifier', so we'll call them tid_ce & tid_sn)
2. Create a Unique Index on each table using the table's PK and the table id field.
3. Add a tinyint field to your 'Deductions' table to store the second half of the foreign key (the Table ID)
4. Create 2 foreign keys in your 'Deductions' table (You can't enforce referential integrity, because either one key will be valid or the other...but never both:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Deductions]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Deductions_employees_ce] FOREIGN KEY([id], [fk_tid])
   REFERENCES [dbo].[employees_ce] ([empid], [tid])
   NOT FOR REPLICATION 
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Deductions] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_600_WorkComments_employees_ce]
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Deductions]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Deductions_employees_sn] FOREIGN KEY([id], [fk_tid])
   REFERENCES [dbo].[employees_sn] ([empid], [tid])
   NOT FOR REPLICATION 
   GO
   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Deductions] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_600_WorkComments_employees_sn]
   GO

   employees_ce
   --------------
   empid    name     tid
   khce1   prince    1

   employees_sn
   ----------------
   empid    name     tid 
   khsn1   princess  2

   deductions
   ----------------------
   id      tid       name  
   khce1   1         gold
   khsn1   2         silver         
   ** id + tid creates a unique index **
   ```

**Solution 2:**
This solution allows referential integrity to be maintained:
1. Create a second foreign key field in 'Deductions' table , allow Null values in both foreign keys, and create normal foreign keys:

```
    employees_ce
    --------------
    empid   name
    khce1   prince 

    employees_sn
    ----------------
    empid   name     
    khsn1   princess 

    deductions
    ----------------------
    idce    idsn      name  
    khce1   *NULL*    gold
    *NULL*  khsn1     silver
```

Integrity is only checked if the column is not null, so you can maintain referential integrity.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is long stagnant topic, but in case anyone searches here is how I deal with multi table foreign keys.  With this technique you do not have any DBA enforced cascade operations, so please make sure you deal with `DELETE` and such in your code.

```
Table 1 Fruit
pk_fruitid, name
1, apple
2, pear

Table 2 Meat
Pk_meatid, name
1, beef
2, chicken

Table 3 Entity's
PK_entityid, anme
1, fruit
2, meat
3, desert

Table 4 Basket (Table using fk_s)
PK_basketid, fk_entityid, pseudo_entityrow
1, 2, 2 (Chicken - entity denotes meat table, pseudokey denotes row in indictaed table)
2, 1, 1 (Apple)
3, 1, 2 (pear)
4, 3, 1 (cheesecake)
```

SO Op's Example would look like this

```
deductions
--------------
type    id      name
1      khce1   gold
2      khsn1   silver

types
---------------------
1 employees_ce
2 employees_sn
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically possible. You would probably reference employees_ce in deductions and employees_sn. But why don't you merge employees_sn and employees_ce? I see no reason why you have two table. No one to many relationship. And (not in this example) many columns.

If you do two references for one column, an employee **must** have an entry in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You will need to define 2 FKs for 3rd table. Each FK pointing to the required field(s) of one table (ie 1 FK per foreign table).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you must have two tables for the two employee types for some reason, I'll extend on vmarquez's answer:

Schema:

```
employees_ce (id, name)
employees_sn (id, name)
deductions (id, parentId, parentType, name)
```

Data in deductions:

```
deductions table
id      parentId      parentType      name
1       1             ce              gold
2       1             sn              silver
3       2             sn              wood
...
```

This would allow you to have deductions point to any other table in your schema.  This kind of relation isn't supported by database-level constraints, IIRC so you'll have to make sure your App manages the constraint properly (which makes it more cumbersome if you have several different Apps/services hitting the same database).