# How can I create a foreign key on a column, every record of which may refer to a column in one of several tables?

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys

I'm in the process of creating a social network. It has several entities like news, photo, which can have comments. Since all comments have the same columns and behave the same way, and the only difference is their type — news, or photo, or something else to be added in the future — I decided to create one table for all comments with a column named `type`. It worked perfectly until I decided to add foreign keys to my database schema.

The `comment` table have a column `parent`, which refers to `id` of `news` or `photo` table, depending on the column `type`.

The problem is, I can't add a foreign key which refers to the unknown in advance table, and even more, which refers to several tables at once.

The whole database now uses foreign keys, except this one `parent` column in the `comment` table. It bothers me because it's the *only* place where I can't add a foreign key.

I'm sure I can't create such a foreign key; something in my database design needs to be changed. I decided to create one table for comments to be ready to add new comment types for new entities in the future — video, music, article, etc — and don't run into maintenance hell when I want to add one new column for all comments.

If I absolutely have to create a separate table for each comment type to be able to use foreign keys fully, I'll do that. But maybe another common solution to this problem already exists, and I'm just not aware of it?

Maybe I should create some sort of link table, which links the `comment` table with other entities' tables? But maybe this solution is even more complex than creating a separate table for each comment type?

Maybe I should have several columns in the `comment` table, like `newsId`, `photoId`, to which I can add foreign key?

These solutions just don't seem elegant to me, or I just misunderstand something. My whole perception of this issue might be plain wrong. That's why I'm here. Please share your ideas.

Comment: It was hard for me to choose **one** right answer: the first one links to a similar answer, and the second one is written specifically for my question — both are good. I chose the second one — APC's — because it is more detailed and uses my terms. Thank you both.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreign key refering to primary keys across multiple tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668921/foreign-key-refering-to-primary-keys-across-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have several entities - news, photos.  But these are all just types of (say) items.  Like comments,items will probably have some attributes in common as well as some distinct attributes.  One of those attributes will be the ability to be commented upon.

In this approach you have a table `CommentableItems` **(1)**, with the common attributes.  Then you have some sub-tables `NewsItems`, `PhotoItems`, etc.  It is quite easy to set-up the keys for these tables to enforce the required one-to-one relationship.  Obviously, Comments has a foreign key which references `CommentableItems`.

**(1)**  Actually I would probably shoot myself rather than allow a table called something as ghastly as `CommentableItems` into my schema, but this is just for the sake of example.

Comment: I think I'll really name it as `Commentable`, because I can't think of another more appropriate name. `Entity` would be too broad name, because not all entities are commentable.