# How do I structure my database so that two tables that constitute the same "element" link to another?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I read up on database structuring and normalization and decided to remodel the database behind my learning thingie to reduce redundancy.

I have different types of entries that can be learned. **Gap texts**/cloze tests (one text, many gaps) and simple **known-unknown** (one question, one answer) types.

Now I'm in a bit of a pickle:

- gaps need *exactly* the same columns in the user table as question-answer types
- but they need less columns than question-answer types (all that info is in the `clozetests` table)
- I'm wishing for a "*magic*" foreign key that can point both to the gap and the terms table. Of course their ids would overlap though. I don't like having both a term_id and gap_id in the user_terms, that seems unelegant (but is the most elegant I can come up with after googling for a while, not knowing what name this *pickle* goes by).
- I don't want a `user_gaps` analogue to `user_terms`, because then I'd be in the same pickle when it comes to the table `user_terms_answers`.

I put up this *cardboard cutout collage* of my schema. I didn't remove the stuff that isn't relevant for this question, but I can do that if anyone's confusion can be remedied like that. I think it looks super tidy already. Tidier than my mental concept of this at least.
Did I say any help would be greatly appreciated? Answerers might find themselves adulated for their wisdom.
[image: Cutout of my schema diagram]

---

**Background story**  if you care, it's not really relevant to the question.
Before remodeling I had them all in one table (because I added the gap texts in a hurry), so that the gap texts were "normal" items without answers, while the gaps where items without questions. The application linked them together.

---

### Edit

I added an answer after SO coughed up some helpful posts. I'm not yet 100% satisfied. I try to write views for common queries to this set up now and again I feel like I'll have to pull application logic for something that is database turf.

Comment: The main problem here is to tell a story. Who, what, where when and why? It is learnable, but it is test -- well, maybe. Who is taking a test? Is one close-text the whole test? Are there many questions in a test? Can one term be repeated in many gaps? Is there a score? Can the test be taken several times? Languages? What kind of a test is this?

Comment: @Damir Sudarevic It's "simple" repetition learning. Gaps and Terms are the same "unit". Gaps have a higher order unit, a gap text, in which they are included (so in a way the gap text constitutes the question part of many gaps, while for a term one question maps to one answer. It's not a test for evaluating people. I think I'll put my schema on CodeReview when I'm finished, then I'll explain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After editing my question some Stackoverflow started relating the right questions to me.

I knew this was a common problem, but I *really* couldn't find it, just couldn't come up with the right search terms, I guess.

The following threads address similar problems and I'll try to apply that logic to my own design. They all propose adding a higher-level description for (in my case terms and gaps) like items. That makes sense and reflects the logic behind my application.

- [Relation Database Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325161/relational-database-design-mysql)
- [Foreign Key on multiple columns in one of several tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294495/how-can-i-create-a-foreign-key-on-a-column-every-record-of-which-may-refer-to-a)
- [Foreign Key refering to primary key across multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668921/foreign-key-refering-to-primary-keys-across-multiple-tables)
- And [this good person](http://laughingmeme.org/2004/08/14/mysql-and-the-case-for-class-table-inheritance/) illustrates how to retrieve the data once it's broken up across tables. He also clues me to the keyword *class table inheritance*, so now I know what to google.

I'll post back with my edited schema once I've applied this. It does seem more elegant like this.

#### Edited schema

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comment, it is hard to answer without knowing the whole story. So, here is a story and a model to match. See if you can adapt this to you example.

School of (foreign) **languages** offers **exams** for several **levels** of **language** proficiency. The school maintains many pre-made **tests** for each **level** of each **language** (`LangLevelTestNo`).

Each **test** contains several (many) **questions**. Each **question** can be **simple** or of the **close-text-type**. **Correct answers** are stored for each **simple question**. Correct **terms** are stored for each **gap** of each **close-text question**.

**Student** can take an **exam** for a **language level** and is presented with one of the pre-made **tests**. For each **student exam**, the **exam form** is maintained which stores students **answers** for each **question** of the **exam**. Like a **question**, an **answer** may be of a **simple** of of a **close-text-type**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really recognise my schema in this setup anymore. Maybe the biggest problem in understanding is the term *cloze test*. This was supposed to be a synonym of **gap text**, which is just something like: Corvus cornix is a member of the family `_______` and the order `__________` where the user would have to enter Corvidae and Passeriformes respectively. But the sentence is the "question" for multiple answer-fields. Actually the text in the DB would not contain `_____` but [Corvidae] instead. The app masks it. A term is simply something like: *Fuß in German is in English*: Foot

Comment: I'm actually okay with my solution below though. I'll post my full schema (including the users table) on CodeReview, when it's more complete and then I'll **make sure** that I tell a good story. I guess after brooding over this for so long, it seemed obvious. Thanks a lot for your input, even if I can't apply it to my problem anymore. I'd love to have your eyes on it, when I properly lay it out there.