# Does this look like a proper database design?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I've been working for a few weeks trying to read about all the in's and out's of designing a proper database structure. After many attempts, I think I may have what is considered correct. But i'm skeptical on whether or not I have joining tables and foreign keys setup correctly. The database I'm working on consists of several relationships all revolved around a song_title. The linked image is what I have currently. Does this look right?

Each song can have many colors.

One color can have only one set of values.

Each color value has only one set of dmx values.

Each color value has only one set of percent values.

Each song can have only one mood.

Each mood can apply to multiple songs.

Each song can have only one time_signature.

Each time_signature can apply to multiple songs.

Each song can have only one arrangement.

Each arrangement can apply to multiple songs.

Each song can have only one tempo.

Each tempo can apply to multiple songs.

Each song can have only one fire_cue.

Each fire_cue can apply to multiple songs.

One song can have multiple mp3 files.

Each mp3 can belong to only one song.

One song can have multiple img files.

Each img can belong to only one song.

[image]

Comment: This might be one way of doing it. There are certainly others. None of them are 'right' or 'wrong'. Sometimes the only way to proceed is to build something and see how well it works.

Comment: Holy crap.  You can probably get rid of at least 1/3 of these tables (maybe more).  Q: What part of "time_signature" (for example), *isn't* an intrinsic property of a particular "song"?

Comment: time_signature, mood, arrangement, fire_cue, and tempo are all tables that will have set values. So tempo will basically be a static table that never changes, but I need a way to identify the tempo of the song.

Comment: Re how to design see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28124305/3404097). Or the first part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27402464/3404097). Nb *X* has-a *Y*  is a trivial pitiful inadequate generic underexplained relationship & not what you need. *Tables* represent n-parameter application relationships. *Lines* represent projections of those and/or constraints. PS: Constant relationships are also made accessible (especially when big) as boolean functions (eg *X* > *Y*) or as functions (eg sin(*X*)). PPS: @FoggyDay means, why not song_title time_signature VARCHAR(45)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *correct* or *right* way to design a database. What you have here looks well thought out and could be a way to design your database for your needs. More importantly than answering if this is a proper database design (which anyone could give their **opinion** on and they could all differ) is whether the database works for the design of your infrastructure.

Are you planning on using this database or are you just messing around with ERDs and design? If you are going to use it, you might find that your complexity might be too high. You might find that relationships you have 'created' do not need to exist (same goes with entire tables or entities even). It is hard to answer your question, because opinions are all that you will receive in answers. I think it is important for you to start writing your program and writing queries and calling the information you have stored in your database to truly find if your database design is ideal!

Comment: This is something that I'm actively trying to get working. My setback has been on learning how things should be organized inside of a database. My original form was going to have one table with each of the above values in one row. I was told that this was inefficient and let room for duplicates / errors as I perform CRUD operations. So I looked into the normal forms and now i'm here trying to figure out if I've done things correct.

You may be correct that I'm making relationships that aren't necessary. I'm trying to find those inefficiencies.