# How to store stops in routes in MySQL DB?

Tags: php, mysql, database, routes

In PHP MySQL I want to design a database for routes with dynamic tracking of vans.

How do I put stops in the database?

I know how to store start and end points

```
route(r_id, start_point,end_point)
```

but not stops between points
when there are many routes with different start and end points and different stops in different routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
point(p_id,...)
route(r_id,start_point,end_point)
stop(r_id,stop_number_within_route,p_id)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28124305/3404097) and its question. Extract:

> The tables in a relational database describe the state of an
> application. Each table has an associated fill-in-the-(named-)blanks
> statement (predicate).
>
> The parameters of the predicate are the columns of the table.
>
> The rows that make a table's predicate true go in the table. The rows
> that make if false stay out.
>
> You need to decide on sufficient predicates to be able to fully
> describe the the stituations of your application. This includes
> abstract things like routes and transactions and events and schedules
> and assignments etc. (Once we have sufficitent predicates/tables we
> improve them via techniques like normalization.)

Comment: sir i cant under point for example a route A to E has 3 stops B, C , D what will be p_id in stop ??
how i will describe it in database  `point(?,..??.)
route(1,A,E)
stop(1,3,??) `
 if i say P_id as 2 for b  `point(2,..B.)
route(1,A,E)
stop(1,3,2) ` where will C D goes @philipxy

Comment: Your p_ids are currently letters of the alphabet. So you example has rows point(A,*other point info*), route(1,A,E), stop(1,1,A), stop(1,2,B), stop(1,3,C). Read the link about finding parameterized natural language statements that describe your application, each of which gets a table.