# Relationship to differents tables according the type of account

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have the following database diagram and I have a little trouble making some of the realtions.
[image]

So the question is. In Users table, I want AccoutnType to reference ClientId, LaywerId or AgentId according to the type of account on that user. How I can do that? I'm using EF Core.

Comment: I assume by type, you mean it'll be a foreign key, referencing 3 different PK's? Either `ClientID`, `LaywerID` (Is that meant to be lawyer?) or `AgentID`? You'll need 3 separate columns for this; you can't have 1 column which is a foreign key that references 1 of 3 different tables based on *x*.

Comment: Do the clients, lawyers and agents actually have different fields associated with them? Or do they share most (or even all) of their attributes in common? Why not just have a People table, and then a "Role" column with a number to indicate if they're a client, lawyer or agent? And then a Roles table to enumerate the various roles. (Or if one person can have multiple roles, you could have a third table to allow for a many-to-many scenario.). That way your Users table would always just have a foreign key to the People table, which is simpler and a higher level of abstraction.

Comment: Much better idea ^

Comment: In your case, a client can have only 1 lawyer.  How about of a client decide to use different lawyer on different case?

Comment: This seems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668921/foreign-key-referring-to-primary-keys-across-multiple-tables).

Comment: @ADyson i have already think about this scenario, but first they have totally different columns, but let's say if they have most of all in common, ervery client must have lawyer and agent, so this mean foreign key to same table, I dont know if this is possible.

Comment: yes a foreign key to the same table is allowed. It's actually a fairly common scenario (for example, if you want to represent something like a parent-child relationship) and it would work fine for your purpose I think.