# If a foreign key refers to multiple tables, how can we create a table and insert values?

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

In SQLite, if a foreign key refers to multiple tables, how can we create a table and insert values? Trying to insert values I got a "foreign key constraint failed" message:

```
CREATE TABLE ClientPhone
(
    phone   VARCHAR(10),
    clientID    INTEGER,              
    
Primary Key (phone),
Foreign key (clientID) REFERENCES CompanyClient(clientID) on update cascade on delete cascade,
Foreign key (clientID) REFERENCES PersonalClient(clientID) on update cascade on delete cascade 
);

INSERT INTO ClientPhone VALUES(0402563698,101234);
INSERT INTO ClientPhone VALUES(0427841235,102356);
INSERT INTO ClientPhone VALUES(0465123002,107845);
INSERT INTO ClientPhone VALUES(0401258741,109632);
```

[image]

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]. 1 FK can reference 1 table, so what are you trying to say? Better try to say what constraint/restriction/limitation you want to hold without (mis)using the term "FK". PS This will be a faq. [How  much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: *... if a foreign key refers to multiple tables...* A foreign key should reference 1 table.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable foreign keys before insertions:

```sql
PRAGMA foreign_keys=0;
```

Even if SQLite allows this ddl, this is a bad idea. You should reverse fk directions. Also, see this [Foreign key referring to primary keys across multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668921/foreign-key-referring-to-primary-keys-across-multiple-tables)